# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback function not found or invalid function name

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "questo_block_styles" not found or invalid function name in /Users/gebruiker/Local Sites/questo/app/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308 Stack

this is the error i keep getting when trying to load a css file in my frontend of my custom blocks in wordpress.

code i get the error on:

```
function questo_block_styles()
{
 wp_register_style( 'image-block', _get_plugin_url() . '/blocks/block-details/style.css');
 wp_enqueue_style('image-block');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'questo_block_styles');
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the errors comes from those few lines of code?

Comment: it says so indeed

Answer (score 0):

in my file i also have a namespace.

i removed this namespace and now it worked, i cannot explain why it did not work with the namespace included